# Hello how can i find the biggest average passangers in this array and the company with it?

Tags: javascript

```js
function solve(input) {
  let avioCompanies = Number(input.shift())
  for (let i = 1; i <= avioCompanies; i++) {
    var command = input.shift()
    let passangers = Number(input.shift())
    let avg = 0
    let count2 = 0
    while (passangers !== "Finish") {
      avg += passangers
      count2++
      passangers = input.shift()
    }
    avg /= count2
    console.log(`${command}: ${Math.floor(avg)} passengers.`);


  }
  console.log(``);
}
solve([2, "Qatar Airways", 95, 231, 323, "Finish", "LOT", 76, 89, 55, "Finish"])
```

Comment: You should improve your question and explain what the input means and what exactly you are trying to find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to keep track of the max while you are calculating the averages:

```
function findMaxAverage(input) {
    let numCompanies = Number(input.shift());
    let maxAvg = 0; maxCompany = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < numCompanies; i++) {
        let company = input.shift();
        let passengers = Number(input.shift());
        let total = 0;
        let count = 0;
        while (passengers !== "Finish") {
            total += passengers;
            count++;
            passengers = input.shift();
        }
        let avg = total / count;
        console.log(`${company}: ${Math.floor(avg)} passengers.`);
        if (avg > maxAvg) {
            maxAvg = avg;
            maxCompany = company;
        }

    }
    console.log(`----------`);
    console.log(`Maximum: ${maxCompany} with an average of ${Math.floor(maxAvg)} passengers.`);
}

findMaxAverage([2, "Qatar Airways", 95, 231, 323, "Finish", "LOT", 76, 89, 55, "Finish"]);
```